# re.findall - Matching ids with names

Tags: python, regex, find

I got a small problem in matching my IDs with the right accounts:
The HTML code look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Mike','14','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="user.php?id=14">Mike</a>
```

When I run this:

```
IDs = re.findall('(?<=user.php\?id=)\w+(?=\">)', src)
names = re.findall('(?<=UserWindow\(\')\w+(?=\',\')', src)
```

For example Mike has ID 11 instead of 14. How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTMLs, use a proper parser such as BeautifulSoup..

Comment: But with regex I can't do it?

Comment: For simple cases, perhaps you can, although you're overcomplicating this by using regex.

Comment: "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex. Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML."

I tend to agree. Regular expressions are simply not design for the job of parsing HTML.

Comment: Where did you get the `11` from?

Comment: Use a html/xml [parser](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and xpath afterwards instead of regex

Comment: @tobias_k With Regex, that 11 could have come from anywhere I think. :) Might not even have anything to do with the 1 in 14 :))

Comment: @tobias_k I have a list of accounts. And for each account I have that HTML code that I've posted in my question

Comment: @JörgMäder Why are you linking to PHP?

Comment: @alKid: Just by mistake, I was coding a webpage in php at the same time ... sorry

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the code does work as expected. [**See demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iF6eP4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ought to use a proper html parser like [**beautifulsoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) though:

```
import bs4

html = """<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Mike','14','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="user.php?id=14">Mike</a>"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html) #Prepare the soup!
name = [i.string for i in soup.findAll('a') if 'user.php' in i['href']]
id = [i['href'].replace('user.php?id=','') for i in soup.findAll('a') if 'user.php' in i['href']]

dictionary = dict(zip(name,id))
print dictionary
```

Output:

```
{u'Mike': u'14'}
```

---

However if regex is what you need

Try this:

```
name = re.findall('user.php\?id=\d+">(\w+)',string)
id =re.findall('user.php\?id=(\d+)',string)
dictionary = dict(zip(name,id))
print dictionary
```

Output:

```
{'Mike': '14'}
```

*Note: To get a dictionary simply use the built-in `zip` function in conjunction with the `dict()` function*

Comment: Thanks. The second part worked perfectly

Comment: @MikeT just for the fact, the first one works perfectly too....

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I gave him +1.

Comment: @MikeT I think he meant the beautiful soup solution, but thanks for the +1! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, the problem is aligning the names with the IDs found. Have you tried using one regular expression for finding *pairs* of names and IDs?

```
src = """
<a href="user.php?id=14">Mike</a>
<a href="user.php?id=11">Foo</a>
<a href="user.php?id=13">Bar</a>
"""
import re
pairs = re.findall(r'href="user.php\?id=(\d+)">(\w+)</a>', src)
print pairs
```

Output: `[('14', 'Mike'), ('11', 'Foo'), ('13', 'Bar')]` You might want to tweak the expression to allow for names with spaces etc., but the general idea should work.

You can also easily create a dictionary (mapping IDs to names) from those pairs with `dict(pairs)` will give you `{'11': 'Foo', '13': 'Bar', '14': 'Mike'}`

Comment: I want to build a dictionary with IDs and names, to use it later to automate some processes.